# What's the best way to convert Windows/DOS files to Unix in batch?

Tags: unix, batch-file, dos

Basically we need to change the end of line characters for a group of files.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a batch file?  Is there a freeware utility?

Comment: Advice from someone who has been fighting this for decades: don't. Do not convert data files between different formats, fix your programs to accept either format.

Comment: The problem is with third-party tools that don't.

Comment: @T.E.D. The only way to win is to not use such tools.

Comment: Does Oracle accept both formats?

Answer (score 8):

[dos2unix](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You'll probably want a regex with that like `terminal$> dos2unix *.extension`

Answer (score 2):

It could be done with somewhat shorter command.

```
    find ./ -type f | xargs -I {} dos2unix {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `tr` in combination with `xargs` to do this.

On the Unix side at least, this should be the simplest way. However, I tried doing it that way once on a Windows box over a decade ago, but discovered that the Windows version of `tr` was translating my terminators right back to Windows format for me. :-(   However, I think in the interveneing decade the tools have gotten smarter.

Answer (score 0):

Combine find with dos2unix/fromdos to convert a directory of files (excluding binary files).

Just add this to your .bashrc:

```
DOS2UNIX=$(which fromdos || which dos2unix) \
  || echo "*** Please install fromdos or dos2unix"
function finddos2unix {
# Usage: finddos2unix Directory
find $1 -type f -exec file {} \; | grep " text" | cut -d ':' -f1 | xargs $DOS2UNIX
}
```

First, DOS2UNIX finds whether you have the utility installed, and picks one to use

Find makes a list of all files, then file appends the ": ASCII text" after each text file.

Finally, grep picks the text files, Cut removes all text after ':', and xargs makes this one big command line for DOS2UNIX.